# python - calculate the number of nodes in a Binary Tree

Tags: python, python-3.6

I'm trying to write a function that uses recursion to find the number of nodes, i.e. the size of the binary tree. If the tree is empty there is no node. If it's not empty the number of nodes is 1 (the root) plus the number of nodes of the left subtree and the number of nodes of the right subtree.

I'm meant to use the binary tree class given to me to do this.

This is my Binary Tree class:

```
class BinaryTree:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def insert_left(self, new_data):
        if self.left == None:
            self.left = BinaryTree(new_data)
        else:
            t = BinaryTree(new_data)
            t.left = self.left
            self.left = t

    def insert_right(self, new_data):
        if self.right == None:
            self.right = BinaryTree(new_data)
        else:
            t = BinaryTree(new_data)
            t.right = self.right
            self.right = t

    def get_left(self):
        return self.left


    def get_right(self):
        return self.right

    def set_data(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data
```

and this is my recursive function to calculate the size:

```
def size(my_tree):
    count = 0
    if my_tree.get_data() is None:
        return 0
    else:
        count += 1 + size(my_tree.get_left()) + size(my_tree.get_right())
    return count
```

However, when I run it with this program:

```
 a = BinaryTree(1)
 a.insert_left(2)
 a.insert_right(3)
 print(size(a))
```

I get the following error:

```
Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "prog.python3", line 57, in <module>
        print(size(a))
    File "prog.python3", line 41, in size
        count += 1 + size(my_tree.get_left()) + size(my_tree.get_right())
    File "prog.python3", line 38, in size
        if my_tree.get_data() is None:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_data'
```

when the output should be:

```
3
```

I simply don't understand what I'm doing wrong, but I'm pretty sure it must be something to do with the if statement.

Comment: hi @meg, this is a good question

Comment: By the way, ideally you only define a `insert()` function. You compare the data at each step to go left or right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you pass in a valid `root` object and recursion occurs as expected, then at what point can you hit upon a `NoneType` error? Certainly, when `my_tree` is `None`, and you try to access an attribute of `None`. When can `my_tree` be `None`? At the leaves. In other words, your base case is malformed.

Note that testing the return value of `get_data` is completely redundant here, because `self.data` has nothing to do with the height of the node, or the node itself.

```
def size(my_tree):
    if not my_tree:
        return 0

    return 1 + size(my_tree.get_left()) + size(my_tree.get_right())
```

Further nitpicks:

- You don't need `else`; that's implied by control flow.
- You don't need an extra variable to store the count, because you don't do anything else besides `return` it.

Comment: Thank you so much! that makes sense! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just modify your `if` statement to

```
if my_tree is None:
    return 0
```

The error arises since you are trying to access `get_data` property for a `NULL` data object on recursive call for leaf nodes of the binary tree.

Instead what you actually need to do is `return 0` when you reach a `NoneType` node.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if `my_tree` is None? Then you can't call `get_data()`...

Try this

```
if my_tree is None:
    return 0
```

Worth pointing out that you don't care about the node data to find the size of the tree

The more optimal method is to not recurse, and keep the size updated as you insert/remove elements

Comment: thank you! and i'll keep that in mind for next time :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are **calling get_data()** on non-existent object. So, you are calling *get_data()* on a NoneType object.

```
def size(my_tree):
    count = 0
    if my_tree is None:
        return 0
    count += 1 + size(my_tree.get_left()) + size(my_tree.get_right())
    return count
```

The else clause is not needed. Another suggestion to count the binary tree nodes is to have a attribute `size` on the class, and increase / decrease it as items are added / removed from the tree.

Comment: thank you! the class was provided beforehand and I wasn't allowed to change it unfortunately